# Read excel file in library1 and update excel file in library2/list using powershell in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365, sharepoint-rest-api, excel-services

1. If user enters/updates  raw data in excel file in document library1 which resides in SharePoint online site
2. updated data should be reflected automatically in excel file in other document library2 or in the list.
3. document library 1 contains raw data, document library2 or list contains reports and dashboards to show raw data in graphs

How can we achieve this requirement using PowerShell in SharePoint online?